# Error in Lightining Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have written the code for flow Finish Behavior in salesforce,which is embeded in Visual Force Page

```
<apex:page standardController="objectname" >
   <html>
      <head>
         <apex:includeLightning />
      </head>
      <body class="slds-scope">
         <div id="flowContainer" />


         <script>

            var statusChange = function (event) {
               if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
                  var outputVariables = event.getParam("inputAccount");


                 var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
                urlEvent.setParams({
               "recordId":inputidtest,
               "isredirect": "true"
            });
             urlEvent.fire();
               }
            };
            $Lightning.use("c:lightningOutApp", function() {
               $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:flow", {},
                  "flowContainer",
                  function (component) {
                  var inputVariables = [
                        {
                           name : 'inputidtest',
                           type : 'Input and Output',
                           value : ''
                        }
                     ];

                     component.startFlow("Flow Name");

                  }
               );
            });
         </script>

      </body>
   </html>
</apex:page>
```

Lightining App Component:

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <aura:dependency resource="lightning:flow"/>

</aura:application>
```

After Passing Input Varaibles

```
var inputVariables = [
                        {
                           name : 'inputAccount',
                           type : 'sObject',
                           value : '{!Account}'
                        }

                     component.startFlow("Flow Name",inputVariables);
```

> Error Occured:This page has an error. You might just need to refresh
>   it. Error in $A.getCallback() [[object Object]] Callback failed:
>   serviceComponent://ui.interaction.runtime.components.controllers.FlowRuntimeController/ACTION$runInterview
>   Failing descriptor: {flowruntime:flowRuntime}

Comment: Did you check if your flow needs "subjectNameOrId" parameter? I think you are not passing any parameter.

Comment: How to pass parameter @user36778,can you please help me

Comment: You are already passing value for  `inputidtest`. Just use similar approach for `subjectNameOrId`

Comment: ,after passing input Variables and the screen getting error like this@TusharSharma

Answer (score 2):

For this case the user profile must have the Run Flows enable.

Hope this helps.

JCH

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array of objects that contain information about name, type and value of variables that you want to pass to the flow. You can pass this array to `startFlow` method after the name of flow.

I can see that you already have defined a variable named `inputVariables`.  You just need to update it with right information and then pass as follows

```
// just fill in right details for type and value
var inputVariables = [
    {
        name: 'subjectNameOrId',
        type: '',
        value: ''
    }
];
// pass variables
component.startFlow("Flow Name", inputVariables);
```

For more details, checkout this [link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_component.htm).

Hope this helps.

Comment: ,after passing input Variables and the screen getting error like this@jagmohan

Comment: @SFDCdeveloper Looks like you are not using correct value for `type` attribute. Please refer this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_inputs_set.htm) for more details on `type` of variable.

Comment: ,after using correct value also it is showing same error,please see my latest updated type in Qusetion @jagmohan

Comment: avoid asking follow up questions to your original problem through the comments, instead, open new posts stating what you have tried to resolve the issue and any new issues.